Autostarting chromium with --start-fullscreen or --kiosk options breaks the application
I've tried both making a .desktop file in /etc/xdg/autostart and adding a line to /home/{user}/.config/wayfire.ini, but it always creates a black bar on the top of the screen and nothing else. If I remove --start-fullscreen and --kiosk, it boots up correctly. I've tested each with one, the other, both, and neither. Only neither ever works.
.desktop file code:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Chromium
Exec=/usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --incognito --start-fullscreen http://192.168.1.208:1692
Type=Application

.config/wayfire.ini
[autostart]
Custom_Display = chromium-browser --kiosk --incognito --start-fullscreen --start http://192.168.1.208:1692

(I do comment-out/delete the one I am not testing).
Can anyone explain why this is happening and how I can fix it?

I found that resetting to X11 and editing the /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart file fixed my issue, although this isn't technically a proper answer as it's just a reversion of a software switch.
sudo raspi-config
Select "Advanced Options" -> "Wayland" -> "X11"

I had the same problem on a raspberry pi w/ 7" touchscreen.
Adding the two options --start-maximized --start-fullscreen fixed it for me.  It seems like a bug - I guess --start-maximized forces chromium to get the correct screen bounds.
My wayfire.ini autostart section:
[autostart]
foobar = chromium-browser https://localhost --start-maximized --start-fullscreen --noerrdialogs
screensaver = false
dpms = false

